# Error perl script - can't locate Net/SSH/Perl.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, cgi, cpan

I wrote a simple Perl script try to make a connection to remote server (SSH) and run command. But came up some message I don’t what is about.

Apache Log:

```
Can't locate Net/SSH/Perl.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/s
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 4) line 3.
```

I tried find the file

```
find: `perl.pm': No such file or directory
```

I installed NET::SSH::Perl , log:

```
  root@server:/usr/include# cpan install Net::SSH::Perl
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.27)
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 10 Feb 2017 11:17:03 GMT
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v3.07)
Net::SSH::Perl is up to date (2.01).
```

Comment: Is your Apache process using the same Perl as your command line user? Also, to install a module from the command line you don't need `install`, just `cpan Foo::Bar`, and in your `find` you had `perl.pm`, but you want `Perl.pm`. Try `perl -MNet::SSH::Perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper \%INC'` and check the value for Net::SSH::Perl. That should have the path from where it was loaded. That folder should be in `@INC` for your Apache perl process.

Comment: You may also just try running the script from command line. I find it much easier to debug perl from there as opposed to via the web. From the looks of it the perl install is missing a package. Can you manually find Net/SSH/Perl.pm on your drive?

Comment: Thanks ! I find perl.pm :
`Net/SSH/Perl.pm' => '/home/noc/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Net/SSH/Perl.pm`
Tell me please , how i can do the folder  @INC for my Apache perl process?

Comment: Looks like you have a Perlbrew installation in your homedir. How do you deploy your program to the web? Is it CGI or FCGI or something else? You cantell Apache that there is an additional directory that should end up in the `PERL5LIB` environment variable.

Comment: it is CGI. I dont know how I can deploy to the web, may be you know Looking Glass by Cougar `https://github.com/Cougar/lg`? I think this error was occur because of  SSH connect use.

Comment: CGI is what I meant by _deploy_. Ok. Can you alter the Apache configuration?

Comment: Yes, I can alter the Apache configuration.

Comment: There you go. That should solve the problem :)

Comment: Why are you installing to your home dir if you're installing as root? Setting PERL5LIB is not the correct solution! You should stop installing the modules to your home dir instead!